# Android app is launching twice if i open from mailer link

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, android-launcher

Even though this question is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693950/application-is-launching-twice-if-opening-from-a-hyperlink), It can not resolve my problem. 
My problem is when I launch app through hyperlink in mail, my app is opening again as a new task even though app is already in background. I'm using 
android:launchMode="standard"

If I use android:launchMode="singleTask", It solves my problem but every time when I launch app from home screen Its start from splash screen activity even though app is in background. Please suggest solution to resolve above two issues.

I also read about launch mode in google [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). But my mind do not have that much knowledge to observe. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This might be what you are experiencing: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658

Comment: Please share your manifest file

Comment: Super ji I solved my problem based on your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me with launchMode="singleTask"

Add this to onCreate and you should be good to go:

```
if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
            Log.w("LOG_TAG", "Main Activity is not the root.  Finishing Main Activity instead of launching.");
            finish();
            return;
        }
}
```

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341600/how-to-prevent-multiple-instances-of-an-activity-when-it-is-launched-with-differ/).

Thanks buddy.